# how to search in a string includes \n by re.search

Tags: python, string, python-3.8

I am using python 3.8. I have an string as following:

```
s="V    n :=
v1  5 ;"
```

And I want to get the string between ":=" and ";" (which includes newline (\n)) . I run following command:

```
x = re.search(r'n :=(.*?);', s).group(1)
```

But I get following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

which means it cannot find the string. While when I remove newline (\n) from input string:

```
s="V    n := v1 5 ;"
```

it works correctly without error!
how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the re.DOTALL flag to change "." to include "\n":

```
x = re.search(r'n :=(.*?);', s, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
search(r":=\s*(.*);", s).group(1)
```

Simply use `\s` to match newlines and whitespace. No need for additional flags.

Comment: It doesn't work but re.DOTALL flag worked.